# Как задержать заставку на 5 секунд в xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Доброго времени суток.
На реальном устройстве заставочная картинка проскакивает не успеешь моргнуть глазом, как её задержать скажем секунд на 5 используя (NSTimer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во `viewDidLoad` первого `UIViewController`, который должен появиться на экране

```
sleep(5);
```